# objects follow the same class

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, hittest

I have a problem, I am working on a larger project, and I made a small project to test this problem.

The problem being:
I have made a button which spawns enemy's. When an enemy hits allyCopy it bounces back in the opposite direction. But the problem is that EVERY instance of enemy bounces back when a single one hits the test object.

My code:

my main class:

```
package  {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.ui.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class MainClass extends MovieClip {
    public var speed:int = 3;
    public static var enemyArray:Array = [];
    public var randNumber:Number = 0;
    public static var allyCopy1 = new allyCopy();
    public function MainClass() {
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        spawnButton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spawnEnemy);
        allyCopy1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragOn, true);
        allyCopy1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dragOff, true);
        addChild(allyCopy1);
            allyCopy1.x = 60,25;
            allyCopy1.y = 208,05;

    }
    public function update(e:Event)
    {
        /*for (var i:Number = 0; i < enemyArray.length; i++)
        {
            enemyArray[i].x -= speed;
        }*/
    }
    public function dragOn (e:MouseEvent)
    {
        allyCopy1.startDrag();
        trace("drag");
    }
    public function dragOff (e:MouseEvent)
    {
        allyCopy1.stopDrag();
    }
    public function spawnEnemy(e:MouseEvent)
    {
        randNumber = Math.random();
        trace(randNumber);
        var enemy1 = new enemy ();
        addChild(enemy1);
        enemyArray.push(enemy1);
        if (randNumber <= .5)
        {
            enemy1.x = 526.25;
            enemy1.y =  68.05;
        } else
        {
            enemy1.x = 526.25;
            enemy1.y = 200.05;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The enemy class:

```
package  {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;


public class enemy extends MovieClip {
    public static var hp:int = 100;
    public static var speed = 3;

    public function enemy() {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, killEnemy);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);



    }
    public function update (e:Event) {
        x -= speed;
        if ( x <= 0)
        {

            MainClass.enemyArray.pop();
            trace(MainClass.enemyArray);

        }
        if(MainClass.allyCopy1.hitTestObject(this))
           {
               speed = -3;
           }
    }
    public function killEnemy (e:MouseEvent)
    {
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
        trace(MainClass.enemyArray);
        MainClass.enemyArray.pop();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that `speed` is **static** variable. This means that it's not separate for each enemy, but it's common (**shared**) for all instances. So if you change it, it changes everywhere..

Don't do variables static that often - it's pretty bad practice. The very same thing will happen with life - if you decrease the life of one enemy, it will decrease the life of all enemies (all instances of that class).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It did the job. Is there any other way to change a variable from another class, without affecting all instances but only the one in the hitTest?

Comment: Well as long as the variable is not static, it will change **only** it's value inside this particular instance.

Comment: But say i want to spawn enemy's trough another class. Then it needs to be static right? Or else I cant acces the variable at all.

Comment: Avoid static as much as possible. You need to pass the objects to other classes in order to use their **public** methods/variables. You can pass the whole array if you want, or a single enemy - doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay! Thank you very much, I just started AS3 so all this information is very useful :)